# Inno setup create folder for image files

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to create a folder on C drive with Inno Setup C:\A A  Card Images 
and I am assuming I can use the [Files]Source:"Path to Images" DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
[Dirs]
Name: "C:\A A  Card Images" This is what I have tried but it tells me File exists

So it seems obvious to me that I need to create the folder before I try to add Image files to the folder
**So do I use [Dirs] or [Files] to create the folder?**
And using DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion to load the Images into the folder seems wrong
Because I do not want the Images in the DestDir I want them in C:\A A Card Images

Comment: Then use the location you want instead of `{app}` in the [Files] DestDir. If you use `{app}`, it's going to put them in the application's folder.

Comment: @KenWhite OK I am in agreement with that Do I use Dirs or Files to create the folder and could you share the syntax for either of these thanks

Comment: The syntax is in the documentation, and an example would be `DestDir: "C:\Whatever"`. I've already mentioned that it should be in `[Files]` in my previous comment. You should note that people are liable to be upset if you scatter files all over their hard disk instead of using the proper locations for your files.

Comment: @KenWhite That part I get it is the syntax to create the folder I am confused about my Dirs Name "C:\A A Card Images" does not exist That is what I want to create

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `[Dirs]` section? It's in the help file, in both the online documentation and the Inno Setup help file that is included in the installation.  It says *This optional section defines any additional directories Setup is to create besides the application directory the user chooses*. It gives two very clear examples of how to use it, and you'd do it by just using your folder name in the `Name:` directive, as in `Name: "C:\Whatever"`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes I did read it but Will look at the example iss files once more my use of Inno Setup is limited I have nver tried to create a folder Thanks for the Reply

Comment: If you are installing files to a folder, you do not need to create the folder explicitly using `[Dirs]` section. It gets created automatically by the `[Files]` section. The `[Dirs]` section is only useful, if you need to create an empty folder, or if you need to assign special permissions to a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new directory during the install, use the `[Dirs]` section. The `Name` is used to specify the location. Using `"{app}\foldername"` means to create the directory below the application's directory. To create it somewhere else, specify the full path to the directory.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "C:\Whatever"
```

Use the `[Files]` section to indicate the files you want to install, and the location of those files. You use `DestDir` to specify that location.

Note that users may not be pleased if you create directories and install files in non-standard locations. There are valid reasons that those standard locations exist. I personally don't like it when applications clutter my drive in places they shouldn't be using.

Comment: Not all Windows computers have a C: drive. Most have, but this is not a must. Hard coding directories like "C:\Whatever" is not a good idea in these cases.

Comment: @Ken White I tested and it worked great I agree on the clutter the drive so I tried to uninstall the app and it removed the folder and all the files (images) in the folder So were are standard location I am guessing C:\Program Files Every time I share a app with someone I explain where it is installed and how to uninstall it Still learning Thanks

Comment: THe standard locations are Program Files for your application, ProgramData for your fixed data files, and the user's AppData folder for files that will be modified for individual users.